# Liferay import from wordpress throws ArticleTitleException on content

Tags: wordpress, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to import wordpress content into liferay 6.1 using the wordpress importer plugin 1.2
It works fine on blogs , but fails on the page content - page is created in the structure however the content throws an exception:

```
Starting the Wordpress importer
Creating page  "Hello world!"
com.liferay.portlet.journal.ArticleTitleException
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.validate(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:3280)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.validate(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:3370)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.addArticle(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:187)
```

If i edit the wordpress exported XML file and change from
`<wp:post_type>page</wp:post_type>`
to 
`<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>`
import is successfull.

Any ideas what might be the case? Please help

Comment: Forgot to mention that the environment is Ubuntu 12.04. Suprisingly, it works fine on Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source code and found that this exception is occuring because of the condition

```
if ((classNameId == 0) &&
    (titleMap.isEmpty() ||
     Validator.isNull(titleMap.get(defaultLocale)))) {

    throw new ArticleTitleException();
}
```

So, in your case, the `JournalArticle` which you are importing has some flaws either of the following

1. The article's `classNameId` is not available at the time of import
2. No title is available for any locale or no title is available for defaultLocale

Could you please check this particular article in word press?

Comment: indeed the (defaultLocale) was the problem here. imported content language version did not match liferay language and caused the exception. Changing the defaultLocale solved the problem